# Design questions for tweaking a Power supply blueprint for higher output

Tags: power-supply, ac, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

TI has a very good reference for a 30-W Ultra-Wide Range Power Supply that I'd like to use for a different application that would require about 50W.

Could I still use the same main integrated circuit components (TPS40210, UCC28600, LMS33460, LM337, TL431A) and achieve higher amperage capability at +12V output if I get "beefier" or higher rated supporting components (transformers, diodes, resistors, capacitors).

Could someone please provide me with guidance on the block diagram of the design and the parts that would need to be tweaked to get 50W?

[image: block diagram of the 30-W Ultra-Wide Range Power Supply]

Blueprint: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu231/tidu231.pdf?ts=1632495067445&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: TI also offer online PSU design tools which may be able to suggest a solution that meets your needs.

Comment: The block diagram is fine, nearly all the parts would need to be tweaked.  Getting into the detail basically involves designing you a custom power supply.

Comment: What is the overall efficiency of the boost/flyback supply?

Comment: Sounds like you’d be better off buying a premade unit. PSU design is not for the faint hearted. Unless you’re going to make a zillion, it will be far cheaper overall to buy premade.